# Replace hard-code path with dynamic path of vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have a vbscript that opens a workbook and runs a procedure in the module1 of the workbook, then closes the workbook. Works great. But here's the thing. The path to the workbook is hard coded, like this:

```
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("E:\FolderName\WorkbookName.xlsm", 0, True)
```

I don't mind requiring the user to have the script and the workbook in the same folder, and requiring that they not change the name of the workbook file, but I'd like to just substitute the hard coded path with something dynamic, like:

```
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(VBSPath & "\WorkbookName.xlsm", 0, True)
```

So the path is whatever is the path of the script.

Is that possible? Any other ideas?

tod

Comment: You could pass the workbook path as a parameter to the script.

Comment: you can also do this: Replace(Wscript.ScriptFullName, Wscript.ScriptName,"")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB script + find under which directory I am (like pwd for linux)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099829/vb-script-find-under-which-directory-i-am-like-pwd-for-linux)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try like that :

```
VBSPath = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName,(Len(WScript.ScriptFullName) - (Len(WScript.ScriptName) + 1)))
msgbox VBSPath
```

Comment: I thought I had my question set so that it would email me with answers, so when I didn't get any answers I tried to figure it out on my own. Then I came back here to provide the solution and see that it's very similar to what was posted here. See my answer to my question for the similarities.

Answer (score 5):

VBScript provides various information about the current script and host process via properties of the [`WScript`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at5ydy31.aspx) object, among them:

- `ScriptFullName`: The full path to the current script.
- `ScriptName`: The filename of the current script.

You can derive the script folder from the `ScriptFullName` property in a number of ways, e.g.

- By using the [`GetParentFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22dyy47c.aspx) method:

  ```
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  dir = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
  ```
- By using the [`Len`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42byt104.aspx) and [`Left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk3xcs8k.aspx) functions:

  ```
  dir = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, Len(WScript.ScriptFullName)-Len(WScript.ScriptName))
  ```
- By using the [`InStrRev`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hsxyczeb.aspx) and `Left` functions:

  ```
  dir = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\"))
  ```
- By using the [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5.aspx) and [`Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yscc53h0.aspx) functions:

  ```
  a = Split(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\")
  a(UBound(a)) = ""
  dir = Join(a, "\")
  ```
- By using the [`Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954.aspx) function:

  ```
  dir = Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, WScript.ScriptName, "")
  ```

  Note that this approach might prove problematic if (for whatever reason) the script name appears somewhere else in the full name of the script as well (e.g. `C:\script.vbs\script.vbs`).

Comment: Test your methods with the paths `C:\script.vbs\script.vbs` and `C:\script.vbs`. You'll see that the only reliable way is using [GetParentFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22dyy47c(v=vs.84).aspx).

Comment: @Kul-Tigin I agree that `GetParentFolder` would be the most reliable approach, and that the `Replace` function would be problematic if the script name also appears elsewhere in the path. That's why I listed them as first and last option respectively. The remaining methods shouldn't have a problem with your example paths, though, if the trailing backslash is not removed. Updated my answer.

Comment: Now they're all good except the `Replace` as you pointed out. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out one solution, very similar to what has been posted here.

I created a `WScript.Shell` object:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

Then I used the `CurrentDirectory` as the path of the workbook:

```
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(WshShell.CurrentDirectory & "\WorkbookName.xlsm", 0, True)
```

Works!

Comment: The current working directory is not necessarily the same as the script directory. If they are the same it's just by coincidence (e.g. because you started the script from the directory  it's located in).